# Large infinity symbol in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, unicode

Im creating a plot which has a subsript infinity symbol:

[Plot with infinity symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzAFK.png)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size':16})

plt.title('U$_\infty$')

plt.show()
```

I want to make the infinity symbol larger, but without changing the size of U. Is there a unicode for a large infinity symbol or some other method that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the unicode character ‘U+221E’ to represent the large infinity symbol. To use this unicode in your plot, you can use the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size':16})

plt.title(u'U\u221E')

plt.show()
```

Comment: This is equivalent to what I'm doing (except that it doesn't subscript the infinity symbol), but I need it subscripted. I need a way to make the infinity symbol even larger while still keeping it as a subscript.